# Finding eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-analysis

If the eigenvalues of two matrices are known is there any (generalized) way to tell the eigenvalues of the sum of the two matrices? I have come to hear that no such theorem exists that can handle the general case. I want to ask if it is possible to find and prove such a theorem. If yes, what background in linear algebra is required for it?

Comment: Nope! If there was, then the following two matrices would have the same eigenvalues: \begin{align*}\pmatrix{3&0\\0&0}&=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}+\pmatrix{2&0\\0&0}\\\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}&=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}+\pmatrix{0&0\\0&2},\end{align*}but they don't.